# Implicit compilation constants in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

For the first time in a .NET Core project I've had to use a conditional compiler directive:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Set something here ...
#endif
```

I wanted to double check that the DEBUG constant is actually defined for the Debug configuration, since I inherited this project from another dev team and I've learned not to take things for granted.  The DEBUG constant isn't defined anywhere in the project file but I see tantalizing hints online that perhaps some default compiler constants are now defined implicitly.  For example: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/565

However, I can't find any documentation about this feature.  Can anyone explain how standard compiler constants, like DEBUG, are now defined in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

The `DEBUG` should be defined in VS already. You can find it via the project's properties page on the build tab -> Define DEBUG constant.

And other predefined symbols include the DEBUG and TRACE constants. You can override the values set for the project using #define. The DEBUG symbol, for example, is automatically set depending on your build configuration properties ("Debug" or "Release" mode). More detail information, see [C# Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation)

You can so refer the following screenshot:

In **Debug** mode, and unchecked the "Define DEBUG constant" option:
[image]

In **Release** mode, and unchecked the "Define DEBUG constant" option:
[image]

In **Debug** mode, and checked the "Define DEBUG constant" option:
[image]

In **Release** mode, and checked the "Define DEBUG constant" option:
[image]

Comment: I think your first screenshot illustrates the problem I'm having.  The DEBUG checkbox is unchecked yet the DEBUG constant is obviously present because you're seeing the conditional output written to the console.  So the DEBUG constant must be defined implicitly somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the DEBUG constant should be defined by the VS, it is automatically set depending on your build configuration properties ("Debug" or "Release" mode)

Comment: The impression I get from Googling is that targets from the SDK are imported into the project file automatically during build, and that those targets from the SDK may be where the DEBUG constant is defined.  However, I haven't found much documentation about this so I'm not sure if I understand the process correctly.  And, if that is the process, how the DEBUG constant is defined in the SDK because I'm sure there must be some way of turning it off if needed.